# A lower bound for variance swap strike

Tags: volatility, variance-swap

There is a famous formula for the variance swap strike that reads
$$
K_{var}^2 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dz\, n(z) I^2(z) 
$$
where $I(z)$ is the Black-Scholes implied volatility function,
$$
n(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac12 z^2}
$$
and $z$ is the Black-Scholes `$d_2$' function
$$
z = \frac{\log S_t/K}{I\sqrt\tau} - \frac{I\sqrt\tau}{2}
$$
See for example slide 7 in [this](https://web-docs.stern.nyu.edu/salomon/docs/derivatives/Gatheral%20presentation.pdf) presentation by J. Gatheral (2006).

I want to show heuristically first that $K_{var}^2 \geq I^2(z=0)$ if the second derivative of $I^2(z)$ wrt $z$ is $\geq 0$ for all $z$.

First, write
$$
I^2(z) = I^2(0) + z \frac{dI^2}{dz}(0) + \frac{z^2}{2!}\frac{d^2 I^2}{dz^2}(a)
$$
for some $a\in (0,z)$. This is just Taylor's remainder theorem and is exact.

Substituting this into the integral expression for the variance swap strike,
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dz\, n(z) I^2(z) &= I^2(0) \int_{-\infty}^\infty dz\, n(z) + \frac{dI^2}{dz}(0) \int_{-\infty}^\infty dz\, zn(z) \\
&\quad + \frac{1}{2!}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dz\, z^2 n(z) \frac{d^2 I^2}{dz^2}(a) \quad (a \in (0,z)) \\
&= I^2(0) + \frac{1}{2!}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dz\, z^2 n(z) \frac{d^2 I^2}{dz^2}(a) \quad (a \in (0,z)) \\
&\geq I^2(0)
\end{align*}
where the second equality is because $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dz\, zn(z) = 0$ because $z$ is uneven and $n(z)$ is even, and the last inequality follows from the assumption that $\frac{d^2 I^2}{dz}(z) \geq 0$ for all $z$.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed perfectly correct under your working assumptions.

This is actually what Gatheral also notes in his book 'The Volatility Surface: A Practioner's Guide' (Chapter 11 on Variance Swaps, pages 140 and following). Specifically he writes:

> Now consider the following simple paramterization of the BS implied
> variance skew:  $$ \sigma^2_{BS}(z) = \sigma^2_0 + \alpha z + \beta z^2 $$ Substituting into equation (11.5) and integrating, we obtain
> $$ E[W_T] = \sigma_0^2 T + \beta T $$ We see that skew makes no
> contribution to this expression, only the curvature contributes.

**Caveat**: Skew should here be interpreted in the context in which it is defined in the first place. It corresponds to the order one coefficient in a second order representation of the BS *implied variance around $z=0$* (which is neither ATM, nor ATMF). It is therefore not the 'usual' implied volatility skew $\partial \sigma_{BS}/\partial K$ that most practitioners are used to think about and to which the fair strike of a variance swap *is* sensitive, see [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/27539/why-is-a-variance-swap-long-skew) related question.

Comment: Ty for looking at my question Quantuple. Yes, now I remember above example from Gatheral, which is one example satisfying the condition I imposed on the curvature (wrt $z$). I'll still need to check though if Gatheral's parameterisation is arbitrage free so that at least there is one non-trivial case that satisfies the curvature condition imposed and is arbitrage free.

Comment: I guess that if you work with a real market smile, then it should be arbitrage-free by definition (if the market is efficient). So your question boils down to how good you can locally approximate that smile using a second order polynomial (and you have the answer since as you note it's a Taylor expansion, so you have well-known results to size the remainder). If so you'll have the result as long as $\beta > 0$. Maybe rewriting everything in terms of prices, then deriving those prices to get pdfs will be enlightening as far as arb goes. Good luck!