# Carr-Madan european contingent claim payoff decomposition formula - application

Tags: options, option-pricing

Looking for some clarification to the values of the parameters used in the Carr-Madan payoff decomposition formula.

$$f(S_T)=f(\kappa) + f'(\kappa) (S_T - \kappa) + \int_0^{\kappa}  f''(K) (K-S_T)^+ \ d K  +   \int_{\kappa}^{\infty}  f''(K) (S_T-K)^+ \ d K$$
which represents replication by investments in risk free bond, forward and put and call options.

**what values would be used for: 

1) $S_T$ ? the future price is not known at t=0, so what is used for $S_T$? 

2) $\kappa$? is this the closest forward price to the strike price used for options?**

Comment: As you've stated it, there are no bonds, forwards or call/put options. These instruments only appear when taking the risk-neutral expectation as illustrated in @Gordon's answer. From that answer it is also easy to see why picking $\kappa=E [S_T]$ (= forward price) is useful: the term $f'(\kappa) ... $ then disappears. You should look at this formula as a generic way of expanding any (sufficiently well behaved) function $f (x)$ of a variable $x$ (it so happens that here $x=S_T$) using an arbitrary parameter $\kappa$. Kind of a Taylor expansion but with quantities that have financial sense.

Comment: setting the kappa to forward price lets the second term go away, the integrals can be replaced with the market option prices where the second derivatives represents quantity, the same time the first term would be deterministic given chosen kappa=forward price, so all together it would give a valuation to the LHS=$S_T$, wouldn't it?

Comment: I don't understand your logic. The LHS is the discounted expectation of $f (S_T) $. In other words the price of a European option with payoff $f (S_T) $ at maturity. To apply this to the pricing of a log-contract, just pick $f (S_T) = \ln (S_T/S_0) $ for instance and the RHS will give the semi-closed form formula I gave in the post related to how to use Monte Carlo to price a log-contract.

Comment: sorry I was not clear, I meant that setting the kappa to forward price and taking the available option market data can give us some number on the RHS, in that sense it values the LHS

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: how about the capital K, how this is picked up?  is it somehow depending on the chosen kappa? or just in relation to the current price so that we get all in the money calls and puts?

Comment: The capital $K$ is a variable for integration, which you can change to anything else. For example, $\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_a^b f(K)dK$. It has nothing to do with $\kappa$, which you can set to any positive value.

Comment: but K represents the strike for the options so that it has to be chosen accordingly either, I mean what will determine the choice of the K?

Comment: You can use any symbol to represent a strike. We use $K$ for exactly the reason you have mentioned, that is, people like to use $K$ for strike. Some other sources may use $X$, for example, in John Hull's book. To compute the integrals on the right hand side, certain approximations has to be employed. for example, Gaussian or Hermite quadrature; see the book "numerical recipes in C".

Comment: @Gordon: my question is what value would be taken for the K (or X), would this be chosen so that it equals to current price therefore integrals would be representing all the in the money put and calls or can be chosen in a different way? what would determine the choice of it?

Comment: For replication, you have to use traded options. However, for computational of RHS, the strikes are selected based on our approximation (not based on what currently traded), and the prices of the  options corresponding to our selected strikes are computed based on a given volatility surface, provided by data vendors, where interpolation or extrapolations are also needed.

Comment: As this discussion is also long, we can discuss the computation in another question if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This formula is used for replication of certain payoffs, for example, the log-payoff in [Variance replication using options](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18007/variance-replication-using-options/18022#18022). The value of $\kappa$ can be set to any number, for example, $\kappa=E(S_T)$. This is a decomposition of the payoff, which is not a valuation of the payoff itself, and then further valuation is still needed. For example, based on the above decomposition, the value is given by
\begin{align*}
e^{-rT}E\big(f(S_T)\big) &= e^{-rT} E\bigg(f(\kappa) + f'(\kappa) (S_T - \kappa) + \int_0^{\kappa}  f''(K) (K-S_T)^+ \ d K \\
& \qquad \qquad\qquad \qquad\qquad \qquad \qquad +   \int_{\kappa}^{\infty}  f''(K) (S_T-K)^+ \ d K \bigg)\\
&=e^{-rT}\bigg[f(\kappa) + f'(\kappa) \big(E(S_T) - \kappa\big) + \int_0^{\kappa}  f''(K) E\big((K-S_T)^+\big) \ d  K \\
& \qquad \qquad\qquad \qquad\qquad \qquad \qquad +   \int_{\kappa}^{\infty}  f''(K) E\big((S_T-K)^+\big) \ d K\bigg].
\end{align*}