# Is there a general method by which we can replicate a given payoff?

Tags: options, option-pricing, replication, payoff

I've been studying how to replicate different payoffs using options and zero-coupon bonds, and each time there's a different approach to solving the problem. I've been wondering if there's a general approach that would apply to any given payoff?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the response ! Will that work on any arbitrary payoff ?

Comment: When the payoff is not piecewise linear then you’d approximate as such. Letting the intervals of your strike grid become smaller you’d get better approximations that in the limit need a continuum of strikes.

Comment: For an arbitrary payoff $P$, one could replicate any european option whose payoff is $P$ as a continum of calls and puts  using Carr-Madan Formula, see here : https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/27626/carr-madan-formula and here : https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/26126/carr-madan-european-contingent-claim-payoff-decomposition-formula-application

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses. I suppose this approach can't be used to replicate American payoffs/exotics. What can we use then?

Comment: Not ot my knowledge. This approach is for European payoffs.