# Replicating the square of an option $C^2 (S,K,t,T)$

Tags: options, hedging, replication

Given a vanilla options market, i.e. $C(S,K,t, T)$ for all strikes $K$, is it possible to replicate $C^2 (S,K,t,T)$? So I am looking for a self-financing portfolio which has a price equal to $C^2(S,K,t,T)$ for a fixed strike $K$ and for all $t$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **no** terminal $\mathcal{F}_T$ mesurable payoff $g$ such that $e^{-r(T-t)} E_t[g] = C(S_t, t, T, K)^2$, simply because $E_t[g]$ must be a martingale and $e^{r(T-t)} C(S_t, t, T, K)^2$ is not.

So any deal that has npv $C(S_t, t, T, K)^2$ must involve a stream of intermediary payoffs $ h(S_t,t) dt$, which you can solve for by plugging $V(S,t) = C(S, t, T, K)^2$ in the BS PDE 
$$
\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + r S \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 S^2 \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} -rV + h(S,t) = 0
$$
to obtain 
$$
h(S,t) = -\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + r S \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 S^2 \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} - rV\right)
$$
along with the terminal payoff $g(S) = \max(S-K,0)^2$

Comment: Ok, I was wondering if there wasn't a $-rV$ term missing. But it's the discounted payoff $e^{-r(T-t)}E_t[g]$ that must be a payoff, why do you write $\color{blue}{e^{r(T-t)}}C(S_t,t,T,K)^2$ must be a martingale, and not $C(S_t,t,T,K)^2$?

Comment: Yes I fixed some typos, sorry about that. $e^{-rt} C(S_t, t, T, K)^2$, or equivalently $e^{r(T-t)} C(S_t, t, T, K)^2$, must be a martingale if $C(S_t, t, T, K)^2$ is to represent the npv of a single terminal payoff.

Comment: Ok. Just to add to the excellent answer, note that the expression for $h(S,t)$ can thus be decomposed in 1) the (Black-Scholes) hedging P&L for a vanilla option, 2) a funding cost $rV$, and 3) a third term $(\sigma S\Delta_t^{BS})^2$. Not sure how to interpret/hedge this last term...

Answer (score 5):

I assume your trade $V(S,K,t,T)$ is European. Its payoff is:
$$\begin{align}
V(S,K,T,T)&=C^2(S,K,T,T)
\\[3pt]
&=\max(S_T-K,0)^2
\\[3pt]
&=\boldsymbol{1}_{\{S_T\geq K\}}(S_T-K)^2
\\[3pt]
&=\boldsymbol{1}_{\{S_T\geq K\}}f(S_T)
\end{align}$$
where $f(x)=(x-K)^2$. By **Carr-Madan's static replication formula** (see [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/27626/carr-madan-formula) or [this paper](https://frouah.com/finance%20notes/Payoff%20function%20decomposition.pdf)), we have<sup>(1)</sup>:
$$\begin{align}
f(S_T)&=f(K)+f'(K)(S_T-K)+\int_0^{K}f''(k)(k-S_T)^+\text{d}k+\int_{K}^{\infty}f''(k)(S_T-k)^+\text{d}k
\\[3pt]
&=2\int_0^{K}(k-S_T)^+\text{d}k+2\int_{K}^{\infty}(S_T-k)^+\text{d}k
\end{align}$$
where $(x)^+=\max(x,0)$. Multiplying by $\boldsymbol{1}_{\{S_T\geq K\}}$:
$$\boldsymbol{1}_{\{S_T\geq K\}}f(S_T)=2\int_{K}^{\infty}(S_T-k)^+\text{d}k$$
Multiplying by the discount factor $D(t,T)$ and taking the conditional expectation under the risk-neutral measure $Q$, we get the following theoretical replicating strategy:
$$V(S,K,t,T)=2\int_{K}^{\infty}C(S,k,t,T)\text{d}k$$
Given in practice there is no availability of a continuum of call options, the following approximation is made:
$$V(S,K,t,T)\approx2\sum_{i=0}^nC(S,k_i,t,T)\delta_i$$
where $\{k_i:i=0,\dots,n\}$ are the quoted strikes with $k_0=K$ and $\delta_i=k_{i+1}-k_i$.

<sub>(1) We have chosen as threshold value the strike $K$.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, but I probably did not state my question as clearly as I should have. What I am looking for is the replicating portfolio for $\left( E_t \left[ (S_T-K)_+ \right] \right)^2$. What you gave is an upper bound, namely $ E_t \left[ (S_T - K)^2_+ \right]$. At maturity they will of course be the same. I may actually have found the answer myself, but still checking a few things before I dare post it. In the meanwhile of course if you or anyone else has the solution would be great to know.

Comment: @ilovevolatility What is the payoff of your trade? From your description it seems the only cash flow is $\max(S_T-K,0)^2$ at maturity, as you state in your comment, with no intermediate payment thus by no arbitrage the price of your “squared option” must be the same as the price of the claim I describe and hence the hedging strategy. Can you be more specific regarding the structure of your deal?

Comment: It's true that both have the same value at maturity but they are still different. Take for example the special case $K=0$, then the difference $E_t[ S_T^2] - (E_t[S_T])^2$ is related to the volatility of $S$.

Comment: So you are asking:  is there a payoff whose price is the square of the regular option price.

Comment: @dm63 Exactly, so the question is what is $g(S_{T'})$ such that for all $t < T' < T$ we have $E_t [g(S_{T'})] = \left( C(S_t,t,K,T) \right)^2$. I suspect I'd need options on options but would like to avoid that if there is any other way e.g. by dynamic trading in vanilla options. Since $dC^2 = 2CdC + (dC)^2$ I need to hold $2C$ options at any time, plus something that has a p/l of $(dC)^2$ over a time interval $dt$. It's the last part that I am struggling with, maybe I am missing something very simple though.

Comment: @ilovevolatility May I ask the origin of the question? The natural approach would be to start from the payoff and derive a price process, as in a client goes to a bank asking for a specific payoff (ie. to hedge against some risk) and the bank responds with a price and structures a hedging strategy. Here the problem is inversed, in that we want to derive a payoff from a price process. Is there any assurance the payoff will be unique? For example, in the absence of dividends, an EQ European option has the same price as an American one.

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw I was working on a problem where I *thought* I needed Volga P/L from an option that has a strike at the point where it's Vanna and Volga is initiallty zero (the $d_2=0$ point). Now I can get Volga p/l even though Volga is zero if I look at the option squared. Hence my question. But it turns out, after endless mucking about on this problem, that I don't need this C^2 'fake' Volga p/l afterall. That said the problem itself I find quite interesting in a more general setting, i.e. replicating Greeks of options using other options.