# Black and Scholes pricing

Tags: black-scholes, pricing, black

I want to price B&S with $S_t$ stock price that has payoff, $h(S_T)=(S_T^3-S_T^2)^+$. Would it be wrong if I solved as $(S_T^3-S_T^2)^+\implies (S_T^3\geq S_T^2) \implies (S_T\geq 1) \implies (S_T-1)^+$ and use regular B&S formula with $K=1$? I am assuming $S_t$ positive since exponential. However, I seem to get different answer if I used discounted method of payoff for call price, i.e. $c_t=e^{-rt}h(S_T)$ and put price by call-put parity. Which is correct?

Comment: $h(S_T)=S_T^3 - S_T^2$ is not equivalent to $(S_T-1)^+.$ Take for example $S_T = 2.$ Then $h(2)=2^3 - 2^2 = 4 \neq 1 = (2 - 1)^+.$

Comment: @UBM thank you!

Answer (score 7):

At least two ways to price this:

1. Use Carr-Madan
2. Use $S^2$ as a (power) numeraire, in which case you can price the payoff $(S_T - 1)_+$ under the power numeraire measure.

EDIT:

3. Put-call symmetry.

Maybe I can get another -1 for my answer. Is the purpose of answering questions here to do homework for someone else or to stimulate further study and generate discussion?

EDIT2: I just saw this question has been bumped up by the community, and I notice that I was in a rather foul mood when I wrote my answer above (apologies). Please bear with me, I will write a more extended answer shortly.

EDIT3: Details to answers:

Let 
$$dS_t = \sigma S_t dW_t
$$
Generalization to deterministic carry is straightforward.

**Ad 1. Carr-Madan:**

Please see [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/27626/carr-madan-formula) for the Carr-Madan formula. Since $S_t$ is strictly positive, we can write
$$
f(x) = (x^3-x^2)_+ = x^2 (x-1)_+
$$
We therefore need to calculate $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$. So,
$$
f'(x) = (3x^2 - 2x) \theta(x-1)
$$
where $\theta(\cdot)$ is the Heaviside / step function. And
$$
f''(x) = (6x -2) \theta(x-1) + (3x^2 -2x)\delta(x-1)
$$
with $\delta(\cdot)$ the Dirac delta function. Plug all this into the Carr-Madan formula and you obtain the replicating portfolio and hence the price for the claim. However, there are some discontinuities, so it's a bit messy (i.e. in theory it works, in practice there will be slippage).

**Ad 2. Power numeraire:**

Let $N_t = S_t^2$ which is a strictly positive process. We will use $N_t$ as numeraire. Its process is
$$
dN_t  = \sigma^2 N_t dt + 2\sigma N_t dW_t
$$
Hence, the process $S_t / N_t = 1/S_t$ satisfies
$$
d(S_t/N_t) = d(1/S_t) = (\sigma^2 / S_t) dt - (\sigma / S_t) dW_t
$$
To find a change of measure that makes $S_t/N_t$ a martingale is the same as finding the change of measure that turns $1/S_t$ into a martingale, which is
$$
dW = \widetilde{dW} + \sigma dt
$$
Under this new measure,
$$
dS = \sigma^2 S dt + \sigma S \widetilde{dW}
$$
Hence, the price of the claim is
$$
E_t(S_T^3 - S_T^2) = S_t^2 \widetilde{E_t} (S_T - 1)_+
$$
where the expectation on the right hand side is now under the power measure. But $\widetilde{E_t} (S_T - 1)_+$ is just the Black-Scholes formula with a drift equal to $\sigma^2$ and strike equal to $1$.

**Ad 3. Put-call symmetry**

I cannot for the life of me recall or understand now what I meant :-D As my foul moods are highly correlated to brain-farts (although I am not sure what the exact causal relationship is), it is highly likely it was a brain-fart. However, to atone somewhat for my sins here is another method:

**3'. Local-time method**

Using the Ito-Tanaka formula, we can write
$$
E_t (S_T^3-S_T^2)_+ = (S_t^3-S_t^2)_+ + \frac{\sigma^2}{2} E_t \left( \int_t^T  f''(S_u) S_u^2 du \right)
$$
with $f''(S_u)$ as in $f''(x)$ above. I am not sure this can be simplified further - need to think about it more.

In any case, the power-numeraire method (2) appears to be the simplest among the three methods.

Comment: @ilovevalatility , are you saying as per your method 2, my what I did is correct?

Comment: Not entirely. You will need to write down the dynamics of $S$ under the power measure. In other words you will need to find a Girsanov transform such that $S/S^2 = 1/S$ is a martingale. This will give a different drift for $S$ compared to the risk neutral measure. Once you have this adjusted drift you can use BS formula, but with the adjusted drift instead of $r$.

Comment: @ilovevolatility: Can you elaborate more on the Carr-Madan and Put-Call symmetry methods. In particular, I do not see how Put-Call symmetry will help as it only changes the payoff to another similar payoff.

Comment: @ilovevolatility I am interested to see an answer of using the Girsanov theorem as my background towards applying it is not firm yet, particularly the Radon-Nikodym derivative part. I know how to use it to price European call option though.

Comment: @Gordon finally partially answered your question.

Comment: @Idonknow See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks @ilovevolatility for your partial answer. Do not worry at all. I was just curious.