# Expectation of Product of two European Option when vol smile exist

Tags: european-options, volatility-smile, expected-value

Currently I'm thinking about how to calculate the expectation of the product of two euro option, which is

$E[(S_T-K_1)^+(S_T-K_2)^+]$

I can fit some parametric vol model from the market listed option price. The confused part is when the volatility is a function of $ln(F/K)$ (for example, SVI), how to calculate this expectation.

Many Thanks

Comment: For more complicated European payoffs, when the payoff does not depend on terminal (realized) volatility but only terminal stock price, you can always use the Carr Madan formula. It is model-free, meaning basically you can always use it (vol smile or no vol smile). Take a look here for the formule: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/27626/carr-madan-formula

Comment: If both calls written on same asset and same expiry, then you only get a positive payoff if ST>max(K1,K2). Assume K1<K2, i think this looks like a strip of calls, starting at K2 with first option notional K2-K1 and then higher strikes have more positive notional.

Comment: Let $K=\max(K_1, K_2)$. Then 
\begin{align*}
(S_T-K_1)^+(S_T-K_1)^+ &= (S_T-K)(S_T-K)^+\\
&= S_T(S_T-K)^+ - K(S_T-K)^+.
\end{align*}
The calculation should now be straightforward assuming a constant volatility approximated by the volatility corresponding to $K$.

Comment: Thank you all! Very helpful