# How would you price an option with payout ln(St) where St is the stock price at time t

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes

I know it has to be done through martingales, but I am not fully sure how to do this BSM pricing.

Answer (score 6):

We assume that, under the risk-neutral measure, the stock price process $\{S_t, \, t\ge 0\}$ satisfies an SDE of the form
\begin{align*}
dS_t = S_t(rdt + \sigma dW_t),
\end{align*}
where $r$ is the constant interest rate, $\sigma$ is the constant volatility, and $\{W_t, \, t \ge 0\}$ is a standard Brownian motion. Then
\begin{align*}
S_T = S_0 e^{(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2) T + \sigma W_T}.
\end{align*}
Moreover, the option payoff  $\ln S_T$ has a value given by
\begin{align*}
e^{-rT} E\big(\ln S_T\big) &= e^{-rT} E\Big(\ln S_0+\Big(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\Big) T + \sigma W_T \Big)\\
&=e^{-rT} \Big [\ln S_0+\Big(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\Big) T\Big].
\end{align*}

Comment: The famous Log Contract http://quantlabs.net/academy/download/free_quant_instituitional_books_/[Journal%20of%20Portfolio%20Management,%20Neuberger]%20The%20Log%20Contract%20-%20A%20New%20Instrument%20to%20Hedge%20Volatility.pdf

Comment: Thanks @noob2. Yes, for general volatility surface, we can approximate the log-payoff using the Carr-Madan Formula as [here](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/27626/carr-madan-formula/27628#27628) and [here](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18007/variance-replication-using-options/18022#18022).

Comment: +1. It seems like you've left out $\ln(S_0)$ though