# Variance swap "fast" models

Tags: volatility, swaps, algorithmic-trading, variance, market

As far as I understand, Variance Swap (VS for short) function as follows :

- no payment when entering the contract
- at maturity the VS buyer pays a strike $K^2$ and is paid (by the VS seller) the realized variance over $[\textrm{today} = 0, \textrm{expiry}=T_N]$ (with prescribed constat. dates $T_i$'s), and "the strike is set according to prevailing market levels so that the swap initially has zero value", that is, $\mathbf{Q}^{T_N}$ being the forward $T$ measure, so that : $$K^2 = \mathbf{E}^{\mathbf{Q}^{T_N}}\left[\frac{252}{N} \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \left( \ln\left(\frac{S_{T_{i+1}}}{T_i}\right) \right)^2\right]$$

(Yes,to be correct the $\frac{252}{T}$ should be replaced by $1/y$ where $y$ is the year fraction represented by the time period $[\textrm{today}, \textrm{expiry}]$ but I ignore calendar effects.)

Obviously if $S$ is the S&P (having quite a liquid VS market), for a given "standard" expiry $T_N$, the strike is quoted by market, that is determined by the law of the supply and demand, without any model. Right ?

Now, still for liquid names like the S&P but for non-standard strikes or expiries, I can see how we could infer strikes without a model, for instance by interpolation, I guess that it's enough.

But at some point, we'll need a model. My questions is : what are models used to prices VS (approximations authorized) and options on realized variance (square root payoff vol swaps for instance) in the context of algorithmic trading were we potentially have to price a lot of them as well as options on them, quite fast ?

Comment: See [this question](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18007/variance-replication-using-options/18022#18022). The payoff of a VS can be replicated by a portfolio of calls and puts.

Comment: @Gordon : sorry, forgot to put in the question that I was also interested in option on realized variance, so that their replication through discretized Carr-Madan won't be enough to me.

Comment: Can you please be more specific on the payoff forms of your options? I do have problems to find a good approximation for pricing a VIX futures.

Comment: Have you looked at the Bergomi model(s) of variance?

Comment: @noob2: not seriously. I may ask a question later on, and you can probably provide an answer for it.

Comment: I don't think there is any algorithmic trading/high-speed market making)happening on variance swaps and I don't think it will happen soon. Maybe on options on VIX, but even those had quite limited volumes last time I looked. The replication by a strip of calls and puts is a model-free result. There are some articles by Sepp that discuss adjustment for particulaorties of short-dated varswaps to deal with that var is accumulated discretely. Afaik, pricing of options on var, and particularly consistenly pricing options on variance and options on the S&P is still an area of active research

Comment: @Bram : actually there is, and by the way, even outside high-speed, backtesting strats faster is still challenging. But you misunderstood me, as I indeed said "approximations authorized" : I am looking for toy models pricing not that off but reasonably fast, realized var derivatives. Especially because Carr-Madan (that is replication by a portfolio of calls puts) is not fast enough.

Comment: For my info/out of curiosity: on what venues does high-speed trading of variance swaps occur then? What do you consider to be high-speed?

Comment: @Bram I wouldn't list any venues, but I would just say that I am targeting frequencies where market micro-structures can be ignored, typically on a liquid name I'd say (really really roughly) like frequencies higher than 5mins.

Comment: @Noob2 Concerning Bergomi's variance model, I looked into it yes, but that's already quite evolved for the purpose I want a model for. It's not a precise pricing model I am looking for, but a model allowing fast pricing that I "precise and sound enough" to be used for quant strat managing at a freq high enough such that replication is simply not efficient enough

Comment: @Bram when did you last check the VIX volumes? VIX options are at least as liquid as SPX options by now, especially short-term.