# Replication of variance swap using vanilla option under black and scholes model with nonzero risk-free rate and nonzero dividend

Tags: black-scholes, variance-swap

I didn't find the formula for the following portfolio (variance swap replication) with nonzero risk-free rate and nonzero dividend under black and scholes model :

[image]

I found formula and proof only with risk-free rate and dividend equal to zero under black and scholes :

[image]

An explicit formula exist for nonzero risk-free rate and nonzero dividend  ?
If yes, what is the result ?

Thanks

Comment: Alternatively: [Variance replication using options](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18007/variance-replication-using-options).

Comment: It is not an explicit formula

Comment: How does your dividend look like, proportional or discrete or with dividend yield?

Comment: Like a constant, deterministic and continuous

Comment: @ThomasArpe you mean something like: $S_t=S_c\exp\{(r-q-\sigma^2/2)(t-c)+\sigma W_t\}$, where $q$ is the continuous dividend yield?

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw Yes

Comment: Then the derivations in the links above can be applied

Comment: Can you please give the result ? 
I am skeptical, I never saw it.

Comment: Daneel Olivaw, KeSchn, skoestlmeier, byouness, Gordon.... My post is closed but I have not an answer.

Comment: When you don't known the answer be honest

Answer (score 0):

The first formula remains valid for paying dividends stocks. You should at first compute the forward that takes into account dividends then calculate forward black scholes calls and puts prices for different strikes with that forward.

Comment: Why the first formula is valid with dividend ?

Comment: It is my question how I can compute ? Thanks